# How to add backend to an Ionic app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ionic-framework, backend

I have a friend who is just about done with the front end of an app, written with Ionic/Angular. I'm supposed to handle the backend and add functionality for comments, updates and authentication. I think I'm supposed to use Ruby on Rails so I finished this guide

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

where I basically made a simple blog with comments.

However, I'm really confused about how to proceed to merge the front end made with Ionic/Angular and back end. I looked around and didn't find anything too useful.. so any guides or tutorials would be really helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe check out [Rails and Ionic make love - part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20160315170947/http://www.dovetaildigital.io/blog/2015/8/21/rails-and-ionic-make-love-part-one) it will walk you through how to set up a rails powered ionic app in less than 10 minutes. It also comes with a github repo that you can download and have a play around with. Good luck!

Comment: [Wayback Machine!](https://web.archive.org/web/20160315170947/http://www.dovetaildigital.io/blog/2015/8/21/rails-and-ionic-make-love-part-one)